# mac Book air shows abttery loaded 99 % but still needs to plug the chager

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

hello Iread so many things. it seems no one faced my situation. 
my mac book air battery is loaded at 99 % but if I disconnect the charger mac book closes

before that, it often happened that randomely mac book air closes and to restart again i need to plug with charger. when I check battery it was loaded generally around 50 %

who can help me ?
thank you

Comment: How old is your MacBook?

Comment: maybe 3 years !

Comment: Battery might just reach the end of its life span then

Answer (score 1):

This is typical when a lithium battery fails. You could buy a new battery or take it in for service in the unlikely instance that the charging circuitry is what has broken. Batteries are designed to fail and are consumable. The circuitry is far less likely to fail, but you can't tell the difference without servicing the hardware.

You can learn more at http://www.apple.com/batteries/ and perhaps see what your full charge cycle and other batter information show - that would perhaps reinforce the notion that it's time to get a battery replacement.

[image]

The System Information app can show your your power measurements.

Comment: thank you I checked the battery. 332 cycles only...when 1000 area allowed So ?

Comment: I get the feeling something wrong about system recogniizing battery.

Comment: today situation  : MBA closes with battery showing load 100% and need to plug charger and keep charger plugged to work. Situation before  :MBA used to close suddenly even with a bettery loaded at 50 if not 60 or 70%. I thought it was a temporary problem  : when I restart MBA with charger plug in then I can remove the charger and the battery was in use again. Thank you for help.  Sorry for 3 messages instead of one. Not familiar with this website...

Comment: You did great @francoisecastany - comments can be deleted and are for clarification. They keep the answers clean. You might need service or at minimum a new battery - what is your cycle count?

Comment: my cycle count is 332 only ...